# Multi-window application

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I want to create a application in python using wxpython library with multiple windows which will be inter-related to each other using buttons, i.e. we can go from one window to other and again come back to the previous window using buttons just like an app.
There should be one window on the screen at any time if possible. Is this possible using wxpython library. If so then can you suggest me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really simple. Normally you create one window (usually a frame or a dialog). If you want more windows, you will just create more frames or dialogs.